# where are the JS files in Visual Studio 11 Ultimate when we create Metro apps using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have Visual Studio 11 Ultimate and I am trying to develop sample application in Metro style using JavaScript.

My problem is in every example that I am getting in internet saying that I need to reference to a group of java script file to get winJS functionalities and metro style ( like binding.js,res.js,animations.js) .. And all those samples are made using VS 11 Express Edition .

I understood that express edition automatically add those references ..
But I am using VS11 Ultimate. And it's only referencing two .js files (base.js and ui.js) .How do i get other js files from ultimate... or should i shift to express edition to get all functionalities?

Comment: Looks like a bug. You can copy the files over to your project or copy the templates from (YouVisualStudioInstallDir\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache\JavaScript\Windows Metro style\1033)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The samples you were looking at are obsoleted when they updated their WinJS library from Developer Preview to later version. They move all their javascript library into 2 files, base.js and ui.js, but the samples were still referring to the old WinJS library.

As it is now Consumer Preview, you should probably look at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples