# WinJS.UI.getControl in VS 11 Ultimate metro application

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

WinJS.UI.getControl is not defined in VS 11 Ultimate. Is there any alternatives there to do the same?

I mean, how can i access winJS controls in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know whether this issue is still valid or not and what the original cause was, but anyway: it's good to remember that starting from the WinJS version shipped with Consumer Preview there is no WinJS.UI.getControl() function anymore, instead one should use syntax

```
var appBar = document.getElementById("appBar").winControl;
```

See the official [migration guide](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=242888) for details.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the IDE in terms of your source code. Meaning there is no such thing as it is defined in Ultimate but not Express. VS Ultimate gives you more tools, but does not change the code you have (unless by using such tools :) ).

Make sure you have included ui.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="winjs/js/ui.js"></script>
```

You can use it like this:

```
var appBar = WinJS.UI.getControl(document.getElementById("appBar"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a bug with JavaScript project template included with the ultimate edition, the winjs folder and the JavaScript files in the folder are not included by default.

Just copy that folder from the express edition or add it to the project template.

Answer (score 0):

@Null Pointer 
I notice that you've got [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110558/where-are-the-js-files-in-vs-2011-ultimate-when-we-create-metro-apps-using-javas) about missing JS references in Metro apps.  Personally, I've installed VS ultimate on a number of Windows 8 machines without a problem.

I'm wondering if you're installer had problems. Could you try doing an uninstall/reinstall of Visual Studio and seeing if that fixes things.

Also can you check the contents of the zip files in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\JavaScript\Windows Metro style\1033" and check that they contain the 9 standard JS files in them.  If they are missing then your installer likely encountered a problem at some point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In that folder i cant find any js file apart from some dll's.. And for my another question When creating a new project, the project is automatically referenced to "Microsoft Windows Library for JS SDK" and it only contain 2 js file (base.js,\ and ui.js). I can not see other 7 basic js files

Comment: The folder I mentioned should only have .zip files in it, not .dll's. Have you tried to uninstall Visual Studio and then reinstall it yet?