# open url on a tile using javascript and html in Win8 Metro App

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In a Windows 8 Metro App I want the ListViewItems/Tiles to open a link once they were clicked. The problem is that nothing happens when they are clicked. With *addEventListener* I managed to invoke the item but the code does not reach to open the link.

I store my Tiles like this in the default.js file and I want access to the "link" attribute, they all have one. After that there is the EventListener and the Event (*SelectItem*):

```
var TileData = [
{ title: "Tile01", picture: "images/2.png", link: "http://www.gmail.com" },
{ title: "Tile02", picture: "images/1.png", link: "http://www.google.com" }
];

var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List(TileData);

var publicMembers =
    {
        itemList: dataList
    };

WinJS.Namespace.define("DataExample", publicMembers);

WinJS.Application.onmainwindowactivated = function (e) {
    if (e.detail.kind === Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {
            var TileList = document.getElementById('TileListView').winControl;
            TileList.dataSource = TileData;
            TileList.addEventListener('iteminvoked', SelectItem);
        });
    }
}

function SelectItem(e) {
    var selectedItem = TileData[e.detail.itemIndex];
    var selectedTileLink = document.getElementById('selectedTileLink');
    selectedTileLink.src = selectedItem.link;
    console.log('invoke ' + item.data.link);
    Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(new Windows.Foundation.Uri(selectedTileLink));
}

var app = WinJS.Application;

app.onactivated = function (eventObject) {
    if (eventObject.detail.kind === Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (eventObject.detail.previousExecutionState !== Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
        } else {
        }
        WinJS.UI.processAll(); //It reaches this point
    }
};

app.oncheckpoint = function (eventObject) {
};


app.start();
```

The Template for the ListView is here with its options, after that the ListView itself:

```
    <div id="TileItemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
        <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px;">
            <img src="#" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;"
                 data-win-bind="alt: title; src: picture" />
        </div>
    </div>       

    <div id="TileListView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
        data-win-options="{ 
                            itemTemplate: select('#TileItemTemplate'),
                            itemDataSource : DataExample.itemList.dataSource,
                            layout:{type:WinJS.UI.GridLayout} }" >
    </div>
```

So my problem is that the code does not open the link what I specified in the SelectItem function. I stored it in the *selectedTileLink* but nothing happens after clicking.

Could someone help me to find the failure in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the `onItemInvoked` event of ListView items.

Say, `myItemList` is the id of your listView element in DOM, not the id of your template

```
<div id="myItemList" class="myItemList" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
            data-win-options="{layout: {type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout, groupHeaderPosition: 'top'}}"
            aria-label="Collections">
</div>
```

Here is how you can write this event handler:

```
function myItemInvoked (e) {
    var ix = e.detail.itemIndex;
    var myItemList = document.getElementById('myItemList');
    if (!myItemList ) {
        return;
    }
    var myItemListControl = myItemList.winControl;
    var binding = myItemListControl .itemDataSource.createListBinding();
    binding.fromIndex(ix).then(function (item) {
        console.log('invoke ' + item.data.link);
        binding.release();
        // open a browser to navigate to the url
        Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(new Windows.Foundation.Uri(item.data.link))

    });
}
```

When you `updateLayout` for your listView (or wherever you bind the datasource to your listview), you can call `WinJS.UI.setOptions` like this

```
WinJS.UI.setOptions(myItemListControl, {
      itemDataSource: myItemList.dataSource,
      itemTemplate: listItemTemplateRenderer, //your template element retrieved by getElementById
      groupDataSource: null,
      groupRenderer: null,
      selectionMode: 'single',
      oniteminvoked: itemInvoked
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm really new to Metro development and I'm having problem with the event handler you wrote. I still can not access to the link.

Is there any option to store the "link" as a local variable? For example: with _onClick_ I would run a JS function, which store the "link" into a local variable and open Url with that parameter.

Comment: @Lgn I am not quite sure about what you are asking. Can you explain it in more detail? Have you bind the datasource to the list view? In the debugger, was your itemInvoked event handler being called? Thx.

Comment: I updated my question, showed my code, if it's not too much to ask, please take a look at it.

Comment: @Lgn Your code looks fine to me, but I didn't have to add a event listener for itemInvoked in that way. setOptions is enough for me to get it invoked. If you are using the default project created by VS11 and your listview is on groupedItemsPage.html, then your `handler` should go into groupedItemsPage.js and include the groupedItemsPage.js in the header of itemPage.html. Again, it would be very helpful if you can tell me whether the event handler has being called. Have you tried to use `WinJS.UI.setOptions` in js instead of in html?

Comment: @Lgn Please also provide the information about what is the symptom of your current code so that you can help people to identify the problem.

Comment: Thank you for being helpful. I updated the whole post with a much more readable code and description. Please take a look at it. I use the `setOptions` in js as you suggested. The `launchUriAsync` won't even open a single url, so it fails before that. Am I using the EventListener well?

Comment: @Lgn just to confirm what you are saying, you code crashed in `selectItem` function, right? Do you know which line it failed? One thing I noticed is that you directly retrieve your item from `TileData` list instead of a `WinJS.Binding.List` object. So, is your code complaining at `console.log()` line because `item` is `undefined` and thus it won't have property `data`?

Comment: While Debugging it steps over the `WinJS.Application.onmainwindowactivated`. It does not fail anywhere, at least it throws no errors, it just won't work because it skips functions, but I don't know why.

Comment: @Lgn if you put a break point at `TileList.addEventListener('iteminvoked', SelectItem)`, will the debugger stops there? `ProcessAll` is an async call, if it success, then it should stop at `TileList.addEventListener('iteminvoked', SelectItem);`

Comment: @Lgn did you call `WinJS.Application.start();`? Is `WinJS.UI.processAll()` being executed?

Comment: Yes and yes. The Tiles are there, and the Tiles can be clicked (I mean the default Metro-like clicking **animation** works).

Comment: @Lgn My last bet would be 1. create fail handler for `processAll` and put break points in both success and fail handler, it has to go into either one of success and fail. If it go into fail, then there must be some problem with your html. If it goes into success, then maybe you maybe it is `.itemDataSource` instead of `.dataSrouce`. And you should bind your `dataList` instead of `TileData` to `.itemDataSource`. I hope this is where your problem is, otherwise I can't help more until I run your code. Sorry.

Comment: `processAll` succeded. Did you mean `TileList.itemDataSource = dataList;` ? It did the same. But after `WinJS.Application.onmainwindowactivated` is reached, it jump out of that. It did not reach `if (e.detail.kind…` Why is that?

Comment: @Lgn sorry. I am confused. If it didn't reach `if (e.detail.kind...`, how did processAll succeed?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I forgot the generated code, where the `processAll` is. I updated my post. The `processAll` above should also run, doesn't it? I couldn't insert `onmainwindowactivated` 's function to `onactivated` function.

Comment: It stops at `TileList.dataSource = dataList;`, does not reach the EventListener.

Comment: @Lgn I guess `onmainwindowactivated` is no longer an option. Are you sure it's still an option? I used that in Dev Preview, but not in Consumer Preview. `onactivated` maybe where you should put your code. So check that. I do recommend you to look at Consumer Preview samples if that's the case. Follow this post.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110558/where-are-the-js-files-in-visual-studio-11-ultimate-when-we-create-metro-apps-us/9714408#9714408